# Add commit hash to each commit message

Tags: python, git, callback, git-filter-repo

I'm wondering how to add an original commit hash to each commit message with a help of `git filter-repo --commit-callback`

What I've tried is `git filter-repo --commit-callback script.py --force`, where `script.py` contains

```
def commit_callback(commit):
    commit.message = commit.message + '\n' + commit.original_id
```

But it has no effect, also I've tried to change author name via commit.author_name, it does not have any effect either

Any solutions?

Comment: What would be the point? The rewritten messages would then contain obsolete hashes since each rewritten commit would have a new hash... Did I miss something? By design, a commit cannot contain its own hash in its message. With or without filter-repo.

Comment: Yep you right, commit hash will be overwritten, but it's not a problem since I'm migrating a project to another repository, preserving commit history. So the main idea is to migrate a bunch of commits and add an original commit hash to its messages

Answer (score 0):

I assume this answer comes too late for you, but for other people who run into the same issue:

Your script defines a function to be applied for each commit, but it must contain what needs to be executed for each commit.
At the moment all your script does is defining a function that does never called. If you remove the `def` line (and indentation) the script will actually run like you intended.

The script will still fail then, because the fields in `commit` are `bytes` and not `str`. The complete content of the fixed python file would be:

```
commit.message = commit.message + b'\n' + commit.original_id
```